# buildType goes always to release even I choose debug

Tags: android, gradle

I would like to distinguish between release and debug buildTypes by the following:

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        buildConfigField "boolean", "REPORT_CRASHES", "true"
        resValue "boolean", "REPORT_CRASHES", "false"


    }
    debug {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "REPORT_CRASHES", "false"
        resValue "string", "REPORT_CRASHES", "false"
    }
}
```

I want to access those programatically like this:

```
if("true".equals(getResources().getString(R.string.REPORT_CRASHES))|| BuildConfig.REPORT_CRASHES)
    LoggingUtils.setupAirbrake(this);
```

I even tried to do this:

```
          if(BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE.equals("debug")){}
```

*The problem:*

**BUILD_TYPE always tells "release" even if I click on debug button and choosing debug as build variant. Is there any config that overrides the debug button and the debug build variant to make it as a "release"**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Gradle documentation:

> Library Publication: 
>      By default a library only publishes its release variant. This variant will be used by all projects referencing the library, no matter which variant they build themselves. This is a temporary limitation due to Gradle limitations that we are working towards removing. You can control which variant gets published:

```
android {
    defaultPublishConfig "debug"
}
```

So if you have a local lib and you want to debug it, you should add this parameter.

Comment: FWIW, this problem seems to have been fixed in Android Studio 3, and the correct variant gets published.

Answer (score 1):

Check your import. You should be careful when you use BuildConfig because all the modules and libraries have that and you might import wrong one.

So,

1. delete the incorrect import
2. clean project -> build -> import the buildconfig with your package name

note: BuildConfig will be created after the project is built. Once you Clean Project it will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Your build.gradle doesn't consistently define the type for the `REPORT_CRASHES` resource.  In one place it's a boolean and the other it's a string.  That will certainly cause you problems.

If all you want to do is know if it's a debug build, you should be able to use `BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE` or `BuildConfig.DEBUG` without any additional gradle configuration.  If these values are not what you expect, then you're not building what you think you're building (I have not experienced a problem with them).

Comment: REPORT_CRASHES: They have different scopes, one is a static field and the other is a resource value which I think has no problem if they have the same name. Anyhow, I do not put them together. It is just to show the trials I have tried besides the BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE or BuildConfig.DEBUG also. But all of them have release value even I click on debug button and choosing debug as a build variant.